# unsigned char print correct value like the memcmp

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, memcmp

I have this variable,

```
unsigned char identifier1[12];
```

when I use this identifier is with a cast to

```
const uint8_t*
```

like

```
const uint8_t* getIdentifier() {return identifier1; }
```

and I receive in a function:

```
unsigned char *zid
```

and I want to compare both of them so I use this `memcmp(identifier1, zid, 12);`

And the answer is 0 so both of them are equal...

but when I print the value:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyTag", "%d %d",(int)identifier1,(int)zid);
```

I get different values in both... like `1711428512 1652772888`, but the `memcmp` gives the write answer... How can I print the values to get the correct value of both of them?

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the pointer value of both arrays, which is different.  `memcmp()` is comparing the contents of those arrays and not the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the array/pointer like that, you're printing the address of the data.  If you want to print the data, you can use %s, so long as both are zero terminated.

memcmp doesn't compare the array location to the pointer, it compares the data at the address.  So if it returns 0 printing the data at both addresses should result in identical strings.

Comment: but how can I see the real value? imagine to assign to a variable? and print after?